# Baking homemade pies has made me so many new connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, socket.io

Sorry, if you were looking for fresh baked pies, I only have a web client to help you sell them.

I've recently picked up server-side JavaScript and have added it to my toolbox, and  while I've had a great time learning so far, I've got some code which needs another pair of eyes to review it.

A quick objective summary: this code uses three big JS libraries: [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), [Express](http://expressjs.com/), and [Socket.io](http://socket.io/). For data storage, I've tied in [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/). What's going on is a simple back-and-forth communication between the server code (index.js) and the client code (not listed, I don't want that reviewed yet. If you really need it, I'll edit it in).

For some background, especially if you're not familiar with this technology: with socket.io, there are two main methods: `emit` and `on`. `Emit` sends a packet, either direction. `On` receives data, from either direction too. With my code, I first listen for a connection, and then emit some data to the client, and then listen for a response. When a response is heard, the server sends data back in return.

#### Index.js

```js
/*
*
* Setup app details
*
*/

"use strict";

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var moment = require('moment');

/*
*
* Setup database details
*
*/

var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var objectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/pps';

// Setup all public static files (Styles, scripts, images, etc.)
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Route the main page to index.html
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


var COLLECTIONS = {};
mongodb.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    COLLECTIONS = {
        FLAVORS: db.collection('Flavors'),
        UF_ORDERS: db.collection('UnfinishedOrders'),
        F_ORDERS: db.collection('FinishedOrders')
    };
});


/*
*
* Socket.io Connection with event handling
*
*/


io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    simpleEmit('flavors', COLLECTIONS.FLAVORS);
    simpleEmit('orders', COLLECTIONS.UF_ORDERS);
    simpleEmit('finished orders', COLLECTIONS.F_ORDERS);

    mongodb.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        socket.on('add flavor', function (msg) {
            insertFlavor(db, msg, function () {
                simpleEmit('flavors', COLLECTIONS.FLAVORS);
            });
        });
        socket.on('update flavor', function (msg) {
            updateFlavor(db, msg, function () {
                simpleEmit('flavors', COLLECTIONS.FLAVORS);
            });
        });
        socket.on('delete flavor', function (msg) {
            deleteFlavor(db, msg, function () {
                simpleEmit('flavors', COLLECTIONS.FLAVORS);
            });
        });
        socket.on('add order', function (msg) {
            insertUnfinishedOrder(db, msg, function () {
                simpleEmit('orders', COLLECTIONS.UF_ORDERS);
            });
        });
        socket.on('finish order', function (data) {
            getOrderDetails(db, 'UnfinishedOrders', data, function (data) {
                insertFinishedOrder(db, data, function () {
                    deleteUnfinishedOrder(db, data, function () {
                        simpleEmit('orders', COLLECTIONS.UF_ORDERS);
                        simpleEmit('finished orders', COLLECTIONS.F_ORDERS);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        socket.on('delete order', function (msg) {
            deleteOrder(db, msg, function () {
                simpleEmit('orders', COLLECTIONS.UF_ORDERS);
            });
        });
    });
});

/*
*
* Emit Call
*
*/

function simpleEmit(command, collection) {
    mongodb.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);

        var data = [];
        var cursor = collection.find();
        cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            if (doc !== null) {
                data.push(doc);
            } else {
                //console.log('SENDING... ' + command, data)
                io.emit(command, data);
                db.close();
            }
        });
    });
}

/*
*
* Database Calls
*
*/

var insertFlavor = function (db, data, callback) {
    db.collection('Flavors').insertOne({
        "flavor": data[0],
        "color": data[1]
    }, function (err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        callback(result);
    });
};

var getFlavors = function (db, callback) {
    var data = [];

    var cursor = db.collection('Flavors').find();
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc !== null) {
            data.push(doc);
        } else {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
};

var updateFlavor = function (db, data, callback) {
    db.collection('Flavors').updateOne(
        { "flavor": data[0] },
        {
            $set: { "flavor": data[1] }
        }, function (err) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            callback();
        });
};

var deleteFlavor = function (db, data, callback) {
    db.collection('Flavors').deleteOne(
        { "flavor": data },
        function (err) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            callback();
        });
};

var insertUnfinishedOrder = function (db, data, callback) {
    db.collection('UnfinishedOrders').insertOne({
        "customer": data[0],
        "flavor": data[2],
        "date": data[1],
        "notes": data[3]
    }, function (err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        callback(result);
    });
};

var getUnfinishedOrders = function (db, callback) {
    var data = [];

    var cursor = db.collection('UnfinishedOrders').find();
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc !== null) {
            data.push(doc);
        } else {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
};

var deleteOrder = function (db, data, callback) {
    db.collection('UnfinishedOrders').deleteOne(
        { "_id": objectID(data) },
        function (err) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            callback();
        });
};

var getOrderDetails = function (db, collection, data, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection(collection).find({_id: objectID(data[0])});
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc !== null) {
            callback([doc, data[1]]);
        }
    });
};

var deleteUnfinishedOrder = function (db, data, callback) {
    db.collection('UnfinishedOrders').deleteOne(
        { "_id": objectID(data[0]._id) },
        function (err) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            callback();
        });
};

var insertFinishedOrder = function (db, data, callback) {
    db.collection('FinishedOrders').insertOne({
        "customer": data[0].customer,
        "flavor": data[0].flavor,
        "date-finished": +moment(),
        "price": data[1]
    }, function (err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        callback(result);
    });
};

var getFinishedOrders = function (db, callback) {
    var data = [];

    var cursor = db.collection('FinishedOrders').find();
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc !== null) {
            data.push(doc);
        } else {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
};

/*
*
* Listen for the initial connection
*
*/

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node.js listening at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

There are a few issues I have with this code...

1. **A lot** is repeated. In an attempt to cut back on emit code, I made `simpleEmit()`. It works great. Any ideas on how I could do something similar to clean up the many `on` methods?
2. Because almost every function requires the database, I had a lot of `mongodb.connect`s at one point. I've cleaned them up mostly, but I'm wondering if I'm handling this connection correctly. I was forced to take out the `close()` method on `mongodb`. Will this hurt me? (This is what makes the title relevant!)
3. Everything is in the global scope, should I change this? If so, in what way?

Anything else goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you'd keep calling `connect` and `close`. As far as my DB knowledge goes, you open a connection *once* and keep it open. Here's [an answer from StackOverflow regarding the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607887/575527). So I suggest that once you get the `db` object, you simply just pass it on. In this case, `simpleEmit` should be handed over the `db` object.

I recommend that you use promises in your API. It appears that your mongo API already supports promises. You can simply reuse the `db` from the initial call. [`connect` appears to return a promise](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect).

```
// Your only connect call which resolves to a db object
var connectionPromise = mongodb.connect(url);

// Hook your collection shorthand
connectionPromise.then(db => {
  COLLECTIONS = {
    FLAVORS: db.collection('Flavors'),
    UF_ORDERS: db.collection('UnfinishedOrders'),
    F_ORDERS: db.collection('FinishedOrders')
  };
});

// Hook up your socket connections only when we connect to the db
connectionPromise.then(db => {
  io.on('connection', socket => {
    /* socket listeners */
  }
});
```

The db methods also appear to return promises. [`insertOne` returns a Promise according to the docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#insertOne).

```
// Here's a sample of how a db operation call would look like
function insertFinishedOrder(db, data, callback) {
  return db.collection('FinishedOrders').insertOne({
    "customer": data[0].customer,
    "flavor": data[0].flavor,
    "date-finished": +moment(),
    "price": data[1]
  });
};

// Here's an example of a caller with multiple calls one after the other
socket.on('finish order', function (data) {
  getOrderDetails(db, 'UnfinishedOrders', data)
    .then(data => insertFinishedOrder(db, data))
    .then(data => deleteUnfinishedOrder(db, data))
    .then(() => simpleEmit(db, 'finished orders', COLLECTIONS.F_ORDERS));
});
```

Now if you rewrote everything to take advantage of promises, notice how `insertFinishedOrder` and `finish order` is also simplified. `insertFinishedOrder` simply just returns a promise for `finish order` to consume. `finish order` takes advantage of promises to appear linear instead of nested.

Now that we've started to consider promises, I notice that there are several functions that are not async like `getFlavors`. So that we can be consistent with the promise-returning api we have, wrap the operation in a promise. Also, `each` is deprecated. Use `forEach`.

```
function getFlavors(db, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var data = [];
    var cursor = db.collection('Flavors').find();
    cursor.forEach(doc => (doc !== null) ? data.push(doc) : resolve(data););
  });
}
```

Also suggesting to use a function declaration instead of function expressions. With function declarations, you take advantage of what they call ["hoisting"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting), where in variable and function declarations are visible regardless of where they are placed. But it's also a best practice to put your functions together so you don't have to go out and hunt them.

Comment: This is some good info, I'll need to learn more about promises and the other few things you mentioned. Thanks for the good review